# Display results after form has been submitted

Tags: php, html

When I submit a form with PHP that updates a column in my database, it doesn't display the updated data until after the page has been refreshed.

For example, say I want to delete the word watermelon from the following list:
apple, banana, watermelon, peach

I would have a submit button with a select form, where you select which word you want to delete (watermelon), and then press submit to delete it. The code will run a query to delete the word watermelon from the list, but when the page reloads, it is still there. You have to refresh the page to view the actual updated results.

Here is the code I'm using for my HTML form

```
<form action = '' method = 'POST'></form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your database modifications before your output display in the PHP file. e,g,

**show_fruits.php**

```
<?php
  // validate $_REQUEST
  // call database function
?>
<html>
  ....
  <?php /* now query for list of items after DB call above was made */ ?>
```

Comment: i would recommend using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST (just to be sure the user won't send any data thru $_GET)

Comment: @elibyy: Agreed. I was just being vague to indicate the request method was moot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the action - in your case that should be the name of the php file you want your form to redirect.

Comment: An absent action will just submit to the same page. And fewer keystrokes than `action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` ;p

Comment: Don't be, I was just letting you know. ;-)